# Making a RxJava async task thread safe

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, retrofit2

In my app, I have a service that track the user location then send it to the server using `RxJava`. If the request succeed, I'm receiving back the inserted id, then I could delete them from my local database.

1. Query the database for the points to send
2. If not empty, I post all the gathered point from the database
3. If the request succeed, I delete from the database the posted points

My issue is, I'm calling that observable quickly before the previous task has ended so the server receive duplicates points (same point for both request). I would need to perform the `Observable` on a Single Thread to avoid having another task querying the database before the previous one has ended. I create a `Looper` thread but still, i'm sending duplicates and I dont know why. The server request seems now to wait until it ends before executing the next one, but still, on the next request, it's sending the same points! Gahh

```
    final StoreChangeEvent finalEvent = event;
    Observable
            .defer(() -> Observable.just(database.getAllPoints()))
            .flatMap(pointsList -> (pointsList.isEmpty()) ? Observable.empty() : amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints(pointsList)
                    .map(result -> deletePoint(result))
                    .doOnError(error -> emitStoreChange(new ErrorMessageEvent(error.getMessage())))
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper)))
            .subscribe();
```

It seems like `database.getAllPoints()` is called too soon... Should I add a .blocking()?

Let's say I have 5 point to post to the server (**A,B,C,D**)

1. I query the DB and send A-B-C-D to the server
2. I reveive another point from the device (point **E**)
3. I query the DB and send (**A-B-C-D-E**)
4. I receive success from the server, then I delete A-B-C-D from the local DB
5. I receive success from the second request, then I delete A-B-C-D-E from the local DB

***Result* : A-B-C-D are there twice on the server database because two request was sent with the same point**

Comment: Not really clear what you mean. You may subscribe multiple times and want to be sure that they are executed subsequently?

Comment: Yes, and that the database is queried before sending the point ONLY when the previous Observable has completed... I added detail at the bottom of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1 - Subject

You can try using `Subject` - a thing that acts both as a observer and an observable.

Subscribe to it once and notify it on new events (`onNext()`) from other places. The subscriber will handle the events subsequently.

I used `SerializedSubject` in case you'll call `notifyNewEvent()` from different threads, otherwise you're okay using `BehaviourSubject`.

```
SerializedSubject<StoreChangeEvent, StoreChangeEvent> subject = new SerializedSubject(BehaviorSubject.create())

public void initialize() {
    // Since you access your incoming event from doOnCompleted,
    // need this extra flatMap function so that you can access your event
    // outside rx java chain.
    subject.flatMap(new Func1() {
        @Override
        public Observable call(StoreChangeEvent event) {
            return Observable
                    .just(database.getAllPoints())
                    .flatMap(pointsList -> (pointsList.isEmpty()) ? Observable.empty() : amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints(pointsList)
                            .map(result -> deletePoint(result))
                            .doOnError(error -> emitStoreChange(new ErrorMessageEvent(error.getMessage())))
                            .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent)));
        }
    })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
            .subscribe();
}

public void notifyNewEvent(StoreChangeEvent event) {
    subject.onNext(event);
}
```

## Option 2 - Executors

If you don't access UI, why even bother with subjects and observeOn, subscribeOn. Create an executor with one thread (all tasks are executed subsequently), and submit the tasks to it, leveraging RxJava useful capabilities there.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void notifyNewEvent(final StoreChangeEvent event) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Observable.just(database.getAllPoints())
                // Blocking, so that the thread doesn't exit
                // and blocks on subscribe() till completion.
                .toBlocking() 
                .flatMap(pointsList -> (pointsList.isEmpty()) ? Observable.empty() : amazonRetrofit.postAmazonPoints(pointsList)
                    .map(result -> deletePoint(result))
                    .doOnError(error -> emitStoreChange(new ErrorMessageEvent(error.getMessage())))
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> emitStoreChange(finalEvent)))
                .subscribe();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The incoming event doesn't come from .doOnComplete(). It come from some dispatcher class I have when a location point is retrieved from the GPS.. Sorry, that wasn't clear seing my code

Comment: @Jaythaking Of course, but you access it in `doOnComplete`. Not having it saved somewhere, you can't access it, because during the chain it's lost already (converted).

Comment: I'm a little lost here I have to admit... I tried both and both failed, I have to inform the view once the request has finished, thus access the UI... I use StoreEventChange to inform the view in my architecture

Comment: How does it fail with the 1st option?

Comment: finalEvent variable isn't found anywhere... Plus, I don't understand how it works and the purpose of initialize(), do you have time for a private chat?